# Strapi V4 email template and css style not taken into account after sending mail and at receiving it

Tags: css, html-email, strapi, email-templates

I'm trying to send an email from **Strapi V4**, email template I created.

The mail is well sent and I receive it well, but despite my inline css style in my html file, it seems not to be taken into account when sending the mail, because when I receive it the result is not good compared to my html email template...

I tried to use css inline: it doesn't work. I tried css with classes and  tags in the same html file, but it doesn't work either...
Is there a solution to take into account my css style for this email template?

If I check my html file from localhost on my computer, it works, but not after sending an email, when receiving it.

Just bellow my code (I intentionally replaced some personal information in the html file with 'deleted'...)

```
<div style="max-width: 800px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; text-align: center; align-content: center;">
<img style="width: 100%;" src="deleted">
<p style="text-align: left; color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%)">
    COMMANDE #&lt;%= deleted.deleted.ref %&gt;
</p>
<h2>Merciiiii et bienvenue dans la team deleted!</h2>
<br>
<p>
    Hey &lt;%= deleted.deleted.firstname %&gt;, nous avons bien reçu votre commande et nous vous en remercions vivement ! Elle est actuellement en cours de préparation par la team logistique !
</p>
<p>
    On vous tient au courant dès qu'elle est en route !
</p>
<p>
    Pour rappel, voici les prochaines étapes pour accéder à deleted:
</p>
<br>
<img style="width: 80%; margin-left: 50px" src="https://deleted.fr/">
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto; display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                <span style="text-align: center; max-width: 200px;">Votre commande a été prise en compte et sera bientôt expédiée par notre équipe !</span>
            </td>
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto; display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                <span style="text-align: center; max-width: 200px;">Votre commande est en livraison. Elle sera prochainement entre vos mains</span>
            </td>
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto; display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                <span style="text-align: center; max-width: 200px;">C'est arrivé ! Vous pouvez maintenant en profiter en vous connectant sur le site grâce au code d'identification à l'intérieur</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;">
            <td style="justify-content: center; text-align: center; align-items: center;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<%= deleted.deleted.invoice %>" target="_blank"><img src="https://deleted.fr/deleted-" alt="Checkez votre commande"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>
    Résumé de votre commande : 
</p>
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex;">
            <td>
                <img style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;" src="https://deleted.fr/deleted">
            </td>
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <span>deleted, votre guide et accompagnement grossesse</span>
                <br>
                <span>X&lt;%= deleted.deleted.quantity %&gt;</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: flex;">
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
            </td>
            <td>
                &lt;%= deleted.deleted.amount %&gt;€
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex;">
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <span>Sous-total</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                &lt;%= deleted.deleted.amount %&gt;€
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: flex; margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;">
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <span>Expédition</span>
            </td>
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <span></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                0,00€
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: flex;">
            <td>
                <span>Total</span>
            </td>
            <td style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <span></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                &lt;%= deleted.deleted.amount %&gt;€
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p style="text-align: left">
<br>
Cordialement,
<br>
<span style="color: #e7a6ca">
    <strong>L'équipe deleted</strong>
</span>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center">
<br><span style="color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%)">------ NE PAS REPONDRE A CE MAIL ------</span><br><span style="color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%)">Cet email a été envoyé depuis le site&nbsp;</span><a href="https://www.deleted.fr"><span style="color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%)">https://www.deleted.fr</span></a><br>&nbsp;
</p>
```

Comment: Well, i think i should avoid complex CSS like flexbox and shorthand notation like margin : 0 10px; 
Maybe i should use more table cells (<td>) and table rows (<tr>).

Comment: CSS in email is limited, you can use [this](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/) to check if a property is supported by clients.

Comment: @LS_ Thanks fot the web link, very useful !
In fact i have found a solution without using flexbox and using only basic html and css attributes and it worked... 
I will share my code for community as soon as possible, in case it can help someone in the same situation....